# Why is mark_already and needed_mark both coming up undefined? Python

Tags: python

```
def min_final_mark(learning_modules_mark, assignment_mark, test_mark):
    " return minimum final test mark "
    mark_already = (learning_modules_mark * 0.15) + (assignment_mark * 0.15) + (test_mark * 0.15) 
    needed_mark = 50 - mark_already
print("Needed exam mark: {:.2f}".format(needed_mark))
```

Comment: You defined a function - but never called it, so nothing in the body of the function matters.  Even if you had called it, `mark_already` and `needed_mark` are local variables, that don't exist outside of the function.  You would need to `return` these values if you wanted to use them anywhere else in the program.

Answer (score 1):

`needed_mark` has scope bound to the function `min_final_mark`. What that means is that once the function exits, you can no longer use variables declared inside the function.

To use the `needed_mark` value outside the function, you'd have to return it.

```
def min_final_mark(learning_modules_mark, assignment_mark, test_mark):
    " return minimum final test mark "
    mark_already = (learning_modules_mark * 0.15) + (assignment_mark * 0.15) + (test_mark * 0.15) 
    needed_mark = 50 - mark_already
    return needed_mark

needed_mark = min_final_mark(...)
print("Needed exam mark: {:.2f}".format(needed_mark))
```

Answer (score 0):

`mark_already` and `needed_mark` are defined only within the function `min_final_mark()`; you cannot call them outside it.